# how to compare three array values?

Tags: java, android

I am having three array's

1) serviceDetails

2) documentIdArray

3) servicesArray.

I want to compare `serviceDetails` with `documentIdArray` and if any values matches, I want to get values from `servicesArray` in that position.

```
serviceDetails = (ArrayList<String>) task.getResult().getDocuments().get(position).get("services");`
        for(int i=0;i<serviceDetails.size();i++){
            if(serviceDetails.get(i).equals(documentIdArray.get(i))){
                String strService=serviceListArray.get(i);
                servicesArray.add(strService);
                ((listViewHolder)holder).serviceTv.setText(servicesArray.toString());

            }
        }
```

Example:

```
serviceDetails=(a,b,c,d) documentIdArray=(b,a,f,d) serviceListArray=(1,2,3,4)
output:servicesArray=(2,1,4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested for loop

```
    for(int i = 0;i < serviceDetails.size(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<documentIdArray.size();j++){
            if(serviceDetails.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(documentIdArray.get(j))){
                servicesArray.add(serviceListArray[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
for(int i=0;i<serviceDetails.length;i++){
    if (Arrays.asList(documentIdArray).contains(serviceDetails[i])) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", servicesArray[i]);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it on IDE so it may contain errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic in you code

```
 int[] a = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4}; 
        int[] b = new int[]{ 2,1,5,3}; 
        int[] c = new int[]{ 11,22,33,44}; 

        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<b.length;j++){
                if(a[i] == b[j]){
                    System.out.println(c[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

//**Ans:-**

```
22
11
44
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the second array or iterate through the entire array for each element.

As per your example, you need the position in the first array. Try the below code.

```
    Collections.sort(documentIdArray);    
        for(char c : serviceDetails)
            {
              //This can return the position of the passed value in log n
              int k = doBinarySearch(c);
              if(k != -1){
                 String strService=serviceListArray.get(k);
                 servicesArray.add(strService);

               }        
             }
```